# bug in cv::Max?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

Either I am doing something very wrong, or there is a problem with cv::max. 
I am calling it in the most obvious way possible:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat t1 = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(3,3), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat t2 = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(3,3), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat t3;

    cv::max(t1,t2,&t3);
    return 0;
}
```

and getting:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:500:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:56:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:2627:12: error:
      called object type 'cv::Mat *' is not a function or function pointer
    return __comp(__a, __b) ? __b : __a;
           ^~~~~~
```

Currently on OSX Mojave, AppleClang 10. OpenCV4.1.0. 
I will try on another set up soon.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the function definition in [their documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc40fa15eac0fb83f8ca70b7cc0b588d)

```
void cv::max(const Mat& src1,
             const Mat& src2,
             Mat& dst 
)
```

I suspect you're calling the function wrong, by using `&t3` you are passing a pointer to a `cv::Mat` (i.e. `cv::Mat*`).  The definition expects a reference to a `cv::Mat`.  Remove the & `cv::max(t1,t2,t3);` and it should compile.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a windows re-defintion issue,  Ive solved this by adding this, after the windows includes:

```
//Undefine the max macro
#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif
```

Comment: There is no indication that OP is using Windows. In fact: *Currently on OSX Mojave, AppleClang 10. OpenCV4.1.0*